# Trying to make a validation summary in ASP.NET MVC in div but I have problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a validation summary using html helper :

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Sorry",new { @class = "alert alert-danger" })
```

I'm using `class = "alert alert-danger"` to make errors appear in styling with red div (using Bootstrap).

My problem is that there is a red div (alert) shown before submit shown before submit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQ8ZC.jpg

After submit, I get the expected result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCBdg.jpg

What I need is to hide the empty red div which shown first and let it appear as expected after submit only. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "",new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

I am using

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
```